# Responsive Tester

Tags: javascript, formularios, javascript-metodo

Necesito realizar un tester donde tengo un formulario en el cual ingreso los datos para abrir una pestaña. Dichos datos son la url, el ancho y el alto. El problema es que no logro capturar los valores de los datos ingresados en el formulario.
Mi código está así:
HTML

```
 <section class="section" id="seccion-5">
            <h2>Responsive Tester</h2>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="URL" id="url">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Alto" id="height">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Ancho" id="width">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit-try">Probar</button>
            </form>
        </section>
```

Y este es mi código JS. Está modularizado asi que el primero es la función que debería abrir una nueva pestaña y el segundo es el archivo ppal donde mando a llamar dicha función:

```
const d = document,
 w = window;

 export default function(url, width, height, btn){
    const $url = d.querySelector(url),
     $height = d.querySelector(height),
     $width = d.querySelector(width),
     $btn = d.querySelector(btn);
     
     d.addEventListener('click', e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         if(e.target.matches(btn)) {
             
             if($url & $height & $width) {
                 $url = $url.value;
                 $height = $height.value;
                 $width = $width.value;
                 console.log($url, $width, $height) 
                 
          } else {
            console.error('Algo está fallando')
          }
        }
     })
 }
```

```
import responsiveTester from "./Responsive_tester/responsiveTester.js";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
   responsiveTester('#url', '#width', '#height', '.btn-submit-try')
}
```

Cuando doy clic en el botón, no entra en el if que ejecuta la apertura de una nueva pestaña, sino que se va directo al else que tira el console.error.. Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: quizas el `&` debería ser `&&`?

Comment: @materguru. Ya logré solucionarlo.. aparte de ese error que mencionas le estaba asignando a variables constantes nuevos valores. Así que cambié const por let. El código que está dentro del if quedó así:                           ```if($url && $height && $width) {
                 $url = $url.value;
                 $height = $height.value;
                 $width = $width.value;
                 console.log($url, $width, $height);
                 w.open($url, $url, `innerWidth = ${$width}, innerHeight= 
                 ${$height}`). ```Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Si tu solución es distinta de la que yo he puesto entonces agrégala como respuesta y en 48 horas podrás marcarla como aceptada. Aún así mi respuesta funciona (al menos [en mis pruebas](https://jsfiddle.net/pa1oe98k/) ha funcionado).

Answer (score 2):

Pruébalo así:

```
export default function(url, width, height, btn){
    const url = d.querySelector(url),
     height = d.querySelector(height),
     width = d.querySelector(width),
     
     d.addEventListener('click', e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         if(e.target.matches(btn)) {
             
             if(url && height && width) {
                 $url = url.value;
                 $height = height.value;
                 $width = width.value;
                 console.log($url, $width, $height) 
                 
          } else {
            console.error('Algo está fallando')
          }
        }
     })
 }
```

donde se ha cambiado el `&` por `&&` y se ha eliminado el `btn = d.querySelector(btn);` pues el `matches` no evalua todo el objeto, sinó su selector, y renombrando las variables iniciadas sin el símbolo `$` para que luego no se lien cuando haces eso de `$url = $url.value` usando la misma variable y sobreescribiendola (aunque eso no creo que fuera necesario, debería funcionar igual, pero no me gustaba por si acaso las necesitas más adelante).